# Odoo tests not running

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo

Tests in installed `module` didn't run.

I installed a `module` module_a from website, then I create the tests files in this `module`. The tests didn't run when I run 
`python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf -d odoo12 --test-enable -u module_a`.(Windows)

here is the test file. It's imported by the tests__ini__.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo.tests.common import TransactionCase
from odoo.tests import tagged

class TestBook(TransactionCase):
    def test_create(self):
        "Create a simple Book Order"
        print("testtest")
        Todo = self.env["book.order"]
        task = Todo.create({"name": "test_order"})
        self.assertEqual(task.state, "draft")
```

Could you please give me some help?

Comment: What error you got print in terminal?

Comment: @TerrencePoe No error, the program runs successfully.

Comment: I init a new module module_b, and python3 -d -i module_b, the tests in module_b runs perfectly. It seems to be some problems in module_a?

Comment: run module_b smoothly but fail in module_a? If I install or update a module fail. there must be some bug in my code . check `__manifest__.py` see if the data structure is correct or the code you wrote.

Comment: what kind of test file? Can you post it?

Comment: @TerrencePoe I posted the test file. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add tag `post_install` for the test to run when upgrading.

```
@tagged('post_install')
class TestBook(TransactionCase):
```